# How to encrypt existing data with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I want to encrypt some fields of some tables from my db. If I add `encrypts :'field_name'` to model class, it won't encrypt data already added to db. I guess I have to write a migration that will do this. What methods or Rails modules should I use? I couldn't find it in Encryption in Rails Guide.
Thank you.

I've tried to read Rails Guides and documentation, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a new column to your model's database table and configure your model to encrypt that new column.

```
# in a migration
add_column :model_name, :attribute_name_new, :string

# in the model
encrypts :attribute_name_new
```

Once that is set up, copy the data over from the legacy column to the new encrypted column:

```
# in a Rake task or simply in the Rails console:
ModelName.find_each do |record|
  record.update(attribute_name_new: record.attribute_name)
end
```

And as a last step, delete the old column and rename the new column to the original attribute name.

```
# in a migration
remove_column :model_name, :attribute_name
rename_column :model_name, :attribute_name_new, :attribute_name
```

Depending on the size of your database table and if a short downtime while running these steps is okay, you might need or not need additional changes to your model to keep both columns in sync for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Posting because the other answers are missing the helpful `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods which are [provided by Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.0/active_record_encryption.html#encrypt-and-decrypt).

I recently did this in production and had no problems. Here's what I did:

1. Change my Rails configuration to [accept unencrypted data](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.0/active_record_encryption.html#support-for-unencrypted-data) by adding the following code to `config/application.rb`:

```
    config.active_record.encryption.support_unencrypted_data = true
```

2. Make my column encrypted:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  encrypts :my_column
end
```

3. Write a [Rake task](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.0/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks) (not a database migration because I feel like I may want to run it more than once) to encrypt the existing data using the [methods provided by Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.0/active_record_encryption.html#encrypt-and-decrypt):

```
  task encrypt: :environment do |_t, _args|
    warn 'Encrypting MyModel fields in batches of 1000'
    MyModel.find_in_batches.each_with_index do |batch, i|
      warn "Batch #{i}"
      batch.each(&:encrypt)
    end
    warn 'Done'
  end
```

4. Write a corresponding Rake task to rollback encryption - just in case:

```
  task decrypt: :environment do |_t, _args|
    warn 'Decrypting MyModel fields in batches of 1000'
    MyModel.find_in_batches.each_with_index do |batch, i|
      warn "Batch #{i}"
      batch.each(&:decrypt)
    end
    warn 'Done'
  end
```

5. Deploy to production. From now on, the existing unencrypted data can still be read by my application without errors. Any new data will be saved in encrypted form.
6. Run the Rake task to encrypt all the existing data.
7. Remove the `support_unencrypted_data` option added in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you can fetch old data and persists somewhere, i feel you can use update_columns.

```
record.update_columns attribute_name: 'old_data'
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution that worked for my use case would be [retrieving the raw old data](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#:%7E:text=Accessing%20attributes%20before%20they%20have%20been%20typecasted) from the database and encrypt them in one migration without the need to add and rename columns.

First: add in your Model.rb:

```
encrypts :attribute_name
```

Then write in your migration:

```
Model.find_each do |model|
  model.update_columns(attribute_name: model.attributes_before_type_cast["attribute_name"])
end
```

This will update your existing data with the new encrypted records utilizing `attributes_before_type_cast`.